# angularjs $scope and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new to angular, I've read couple of articles on scope and controllers but I think I still don't get it.

Lets say we have a code

```
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

        $scope.array = [1,2,3];

        $scope.show = false;
        $scope.toggle = function (){
            $scope.show = !$scope.show;
            console.log($scope.show);
        };
    });
```

and markup:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<ul ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="n in array">
        <a href="#" ng-click="show = !show">Click here to show</a>
        <span ng-show="show">Something to show</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Everything works when I use "ng-click="show = !show" in the ng-show. But when I use toggle() insted it doesn't. 
My question is how to change the code to make method toggle() work ? 
How to access the actuall scope than I'm operating in in the controller ? 
Should I use ng-controller="myCtrl" on each li tag ? 
Should I have a controller for each scope that is created by the directives in my markup ?
What is the best practise here ?

Comment: This one is a little tricky, because the ng-repeat creates a new scope for each repeat child. So the variable 'show' in toggle will be the parent variable, but the 'show' in your ng-show is the child variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's being said is true, the `show` inside the `ngRepeat` is different from the `show` in `myCtrl`. However, even if it weren't, there's only one variable `show` in `myCtrl`, so every item would be hidden and shown together when toggling.

If you want to toggle individual rows, they each need their own flag. There are several ways to accomplish this. But to avoid too much logic in the view, and to avoid the use of `$parent`, one way would be to use the `controller as` syntax, and keep a list of show flags, taking advantage of the fact that ngRepeat supplies the array index as `$index`.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function() {
    var myCtrl = this;
    myCtrl.array = [1,2,3];
    myCtrl.show = [false, false, false];

    myCtrl.toggle = function (index){
        myCtrl.show[index] = !myCtrl.show[index];
        console.log(myCtrl.show);
    };
});
```

Then the view:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<ul ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="n in ctrl.array">
        <a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.toggle($index)">Click here to show</a>
        <span ng-show="ctrl.show[$index]">Something to show</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

You could also use an array of objects if you plan to do something complicated where keeping track of two arrays would be difficult. Something like:

```
myCtrl.array = [
  {val: 1, show: false},
  {val: 2, show: false},
  {val: 3, show: false},
];
```

Then the toggle function would be:

```
myCtrl.toggle = function(obj){
  obj.show = !obj.show;
};
```

and the view:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<ul ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="n in ctrl.array">
        <a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.toggle(n)">Click here to show</a>
        <span ng-show="n.show">Something to show</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

**Edit:**
here's a plunkr for each.

http://plnkr.co/edit/sBhY00c5LU4YMeHlqjG7?p=preview

http://plnkr.co/edit/axO9sEB6oHQeDwIRLU4a?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable to me, just wondering lets say that array is a collection of my domain entites, is it ok to attach this artificial property "show" to my model ? is this a common practice ?

Comment: No, I don't think that would be very good practice. Although it would certainly work, it's a good idea to keep your entities clean of any display logic. A better way might be to keep a list of 'shown' entities in the controller using some sort of primary identifier, or reference to the object itself. Or in the example I gave with the array of objects, just replace the value of `val` with your entity, or entity's primary identifier.

Comment: The thing is that i need to show only one item at the time, so would be better just to store index, and use it somehow, not need for array actually. and what do you think about putting ng-controller="myCtrl" together with ng-repeat, that would make scope working.... but i do not know what the consequeces are;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that things seem strange is that `ngRepeat` uses an isolate scope. That means it creates a new child scope off of the parent.

When you use `show = !show`, you are creating a `show` value on that child scope.

When you use `toggle`, you are trying to call a method on the scope that doesn't exist.

You could try calling `$parent.toggle()` on the click event, but that will set the `show` value on the parent scope rather than individual rows.

Comment: It looks for me that $partent to the code will cause some assumption/dependency (what if I want to use my controller in other view?). Aslo staying with show = !show, seems to be like putting the logic in to many places... just still not sure what is the best approach here....